# How can i create a query join two tables with same attribute in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables in one of them there is an foreign key like this

```
type
id, name
```

and

```
section
id, type_id, name, color
```

now i need to create a query to get all of section with that @name, and if the @name match with category.name i need to get all of the sections of that type

example:

type:

```
id= 1, name: oneType
id= 2, name: twoType
id= 3, name: threeType
```

section

```
id=1, type_id:1, name: section1
id=2, type_id:2, name: section2
id=2, type_id:2, name: section3
```

now if i am looking for 'two', the expected result have to be this:

```
id=2, type_id:2, name: section2
id=2, type_id:2, name: section3
```

now if i am looking for 'sect', the expected result have to be this:

```
 id=1, type_id:1, name: section1
id=2, type_id:2, name: section2
id=2, type_id:2, name: section3
```

now if i am looking for 'section2', the expected result have to be this:

```
 id=2, type_id:2, name: section2
```

this is my attempt:

```
Section.joins(:type).where("name = ?", @name).select("id, name")
```

but i am getting this error:

```
TypeError:
       can't quote Array
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return all `Sections` that match a query string by their name OR by the name of their associated `Type`, you can use a `.joins` query to join the `Section` and `Type` tables, and then use a `.where` clause to search for the matching records as follows:

```
Section.joins(:type).where("sections.name LIKE ? OR types.name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%","%#{query}%")
```